# how to work with iburg tool in compiler design

Tags: compiler-optimization

I am a little confused about iburg technology. How it is used? It creates code reduction.But it has terms like `addsi`, `asign`, etc.. How do I use them?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `iBurg` is a code-generator generator that uses dynamic programming at compile time. It's written in `ANSI C` so the operations are also based on ANSI C programming pattern. 
To find out more you can refer [**this**](http://drhanson.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/documents/iburg.pdf).